# How to parse only few rows of json response in RESTful

Tags: php, json

I can't get it working. I would just want to print only first 3 rows (results). Though I can get just first row but that's totally not what I'm looking for. The API sends total 50 results (rows) as you can see in pager (per_page). Here is my sample code..

```
<?php $url = 'https://example.com/events/inplay?token=2645-sl1uDzY3tVvv9M8873472&sport_id=1';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
if ($data === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($data, true);                 
           foreach ($obj['results'] as $res){

         echo $res['league']['name']; 
         echo $res['away']['name']; 
         echo $res['away']['name'];
         }
         ?>
```

This will output all the 50 results. But I would just want to print only first 3 results or so.. Here is the json decodes:::

```
{  
       "success":1,
       "pager":{  
          "page":1,
          "per_page":50,
          "total":43
       },
       "results":[  
          {  
             "id":"584824",
             "sport_id":"1",
             "time":"1516183519",
             "time_status":"1",
             "league":{  },
             "home":{  
                "id":"51566",
                "name":"Al Fahaheel SC",
                "image_id":"55159",
                "cc":"kw"
             },
             "away":{  
                "id":"51565",
                "name":"Al Salibikhaet SC",
                "image_id":"55165",
                "cc":"kw"
             },
             "ss":"0-0",
             "timer":{  },
             "scores":{  },
             "extra":{  },
             "has_lineup":0,
             "inplay_created_at":"1516194754",
             "inplay_updated_at":"1516195076",
             "confirmed_at":"1516194766"
          },




          {  
             "id":"584825",
             "sport_id":"1",
             "time":"1516183524",
             "time_status":"1",
             "league":{  
                "id":"2425",
                "name":"Kuwait Crown Prince Cup",
                "cc":"kw"
             },
             "home":{  
                "id":"49553",
                "name":"Al Kuwait SC",
                "image_id":"32525",
                "cc":"kw"
             },
             "away":{  
                "id":"51567",
                "name":"Al Shabab Club",
                "image_id":"55169",
                "cc":"kw"
             },
             "ss":"0-0",
             "timer":{  
                "tm":0,
                "ts":0,
                "tt":"0",
                "ta":0
             },
             "scores":{  
                "2":{  
                   "home":"0",
                   "away":"0"
                }
             },
             "extra":{  },
             "has_lineup":0,
             "inplay_created_at":"1516194950",
             "inplay_updated_at":"1516195076",
             "confirmed_at":"1516195033"
          },




          {  
             "id":"574814",
             "sport_id":"1",
             "time":"1516188580",
             "time_status":"1",
             "league":{  
                "id":"760",
                "name":"Turkey Cup",
                "cc":"tr"
             },
             "home":{  
                "id":"43941",
                "name":"Akhisar Belediye",
                "image_id":"24748",
                "cc":"tr"
             },
             "away":{  
                "id":"17361",
                "name":"Boluspor",
                "image_id":"6414",
                "cc":"tr"
             },
             "ss":"1-0",
             "timer":{  
                "tm":89,
                "ts":59,
                "tt":"1",
                "ta":0
             },
             "scores":{  
                "2":{  
                   "home":"1",
                   "away":"0"
                }
             },
             "extra":{  },
             "has_lineup":1,
             "inplay_created_at":"1516188226",
             "inplay_updated_at":"1516195076",
             "confirmed_at":"1516188264"
          },



          {  
             "id":"593150",
             "sport_id":"1",
             "time":"1516188608",
             "time_status":"1",
             "league":{  
                "id":"5946",
                "name":"AFC U23 Championship",
                "cc":null
             },
             "home":{  
                "id":"174631",
                "name":"Syria U23",
                "image_id":"49101",
                "cc":"sy"
             },
             "away":{  
                "id":"81107",
                "name":"Vietnam U23",
                "image_id":"49111",
                "cc":"vn"
             },
             "ss":"0-0",
             "timer":{  
                "tm":89,
                "ts":50,
                "tt":"1",
                "ta":0
             },
             "scores":{  
                "2":{  
                   "home":"0",
                   "away":"0"
                }
             },
             "extra":{  },
             "has_lineup":0,
             "inplay_created_at":"1516187775",
             "inplay_updated_at":"1516195076",
             "confirmed_at":"1516187901"
          },




          {  
             "id":"587085",
             "sport_id":"1",
             "time":"1516188609",
             "time_status":"1",
             "league":{  
                "id":"5946",
                "name":"AFC U23 Championship",
                "cc":null
             },
             "home":{  
                "id":"174621",
                "name":"South Korea U23",
                "image_id":"24259",
                "cc":"kr"
             },
             "away":{  
                "id":"160603",
                "name":"Australia U23",
                "image_id":"49021",
                "cc":"au"
             },
             "ss":"3-2",
             "timer":{  
                "tm":91,
                "ts":7,
                "tt":"1",
                "ta":5
             },
             "scores":{  
                "2":{  
                   "home":"3",
                   "away":"2"
                }
             },
             "extra":{  },
             "has_lineup":0,
             "inplay_created_at":"1516187752",
             "inplay_updated_at":"1516195076",
             "confirmed_at":"1516192911"
          },



          {  
             "id":"593172",
             "sport_id":"1",
             "time":"1516189759",
             "time_status":"1",
             "league":{  
                "id":"8467",
                "name":"Bangladesh Independence Cup",
                "cc":null
             },
             "home":{  
                "id":"48561",
                "name":"Abahani Limited",
                "image_id":"317511",
                "cc":"bd"
             },
             "away":{  
                "id":"9244",
                "name":"Team BJMC",
                "image_id":null,
                "cc":"bd"
             },
             "ss":"1-0",
             "timer":{  
                "tm":68,
                "ts":16,
                "tt":"1",
                "ta":0
             },
             "scores":{  
                "2":{  
                   "home":"1",
                   "away":"0"
                }
             },
             "extra":{  },
             "has_lineup":0,
             "inplay_created_at":"1516189167",
             "inplay_updated_at":"1516195076"
          },
```

Anyone's help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: You could just replace the `foreach` with a `for` loop, this should be fairly simple....

Comment: Or add a counter and break when it reaches 3

Comment: Or just use `array_slice` before the loop so that you're only iterating over the results you want in the first place.

Comment: You can count a count in the loop and break after the count reaches 3.

Comment: Please do not comment solutions.  This isnt Q&C.  Please find an `array_slice()` duplicate to close with.

Comment: @iainn Appreciate your input. I'm done.